# WLAN that worked with Ubuntu doesn't with Centos 7

Tags: ubuntu, centos, drivers, wlan

I've got a Dell Inspiron 1545 with a Dell Wireless 1387 WLAN. The WLAN worked fine with Ubuntu but is not recognized with Centos 7.  I've already tried installing the Network Manager package. Seems like a pretty clear driver issue.

On a past, similar thread, one answer by Xalorous referred to a community driver, compiling, and installing it.  Googling "community driver" got me nowhere. Can someone please point me to such a driver?  Sorry if this is a naive question; I'm sure it is.

Another question--would it be possible to get Ubuntu's driver and installing (probably after compiling) it in the Centos environment? Any thoughts on that would be welcomed.

Thanks